# How to rewrite an echo function to a return value for a Wordpress theme

Tags: php, return, wordpress-theming, echo

I am new to PHP and I am glad that I have written the following function (which works as it should) on my own so far:

```
function get_latest_posts() {
    
    echo '<div class="latest-posts">';
        echo '<div class="brick_list">';

            $args = array(
                post_type => 'post',
                posts_per_page => 3
            );

            $latestposts_query = new WP_Query($args);

            if ( $latestposts_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $latestposts_query->have_posts() ) : $latestposts_query->the_post(); 
                
                echo ' <div ';
                    post_class("brick_item" . $termString );
                echo ' onclick="location.href=\'';
                    the_permalink();
                echo ' \'"> ';

                    echo ' <div class="brick_item-image"> ';
                        if ( has_category( 'sample' ) ) {
                            echo ' <img src="/wp-content/uploads/placeholder_1.png" /> ';                        
                        } elseif ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                            the_post_thumbnail(); 
                        } else {
                            echo ' <img src="/wp-content/uploads/placeholder_2.png" /> ';
                        }
                    echo ' </div> ';
                    echo ' <div class="brick_item-header"> ';
                        echo ' <h4><a href=" ';
                            the_permalink();
                        echo ' "> ';
                            the_title();
                        echo ' </a></h4> ';
                    echo ' </div> ';                        
                echo ' </div> ';
        
            endwhile; else :

                get_template_part('template_parts/content','error');

            endif; 
            wp_reset_postdata();

        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'get_latest_posts', 'get_latest_posts' );
```

But now I definitly need your help...
As you can see I want to use this function in a shortcode. Currently it displays first on my page, and Google says, this is because I am echoing the content and I would need to give a return value.

How do I do this?? Is it just replacing the word "echo" with the word "return" ? I have no idea...

Comment: Concatenate everything into a variable and return that variable at the end of your function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have condensed a few statements together for readability but here's what that would look like:

```php
function get_latest_posts() {
    $return = '<div class="latest-posts"><div class="brick_list">';

    $args = array(
        post_type => 'post',
        posts_per_page => 3
    );

    $latestposts_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ( $latestposts_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $latestposts_query->have_posts() ) : $latestposts_query->the_post();
        $return .= ' <div ' . post_class("brick_item" . $termString ) . ' onclick="location.href=\'' . get_permalink() . '\'"> ';

        $return .= '<div class="brick_item-image">';
        if ( has_category( 'sample' ) ) {
            $return .= '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/placeholder_1.png" />';
        } elseif ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $return .= get_the_post_thumbnail();
        } else {
            $return .= '<img src="/wp-content/uploads/placeholder_2.png" />';
        }
        $return .= '</div> <div class="brick_item-header"> <h4><a href="' . get_permalink() .'">' . the_title('','',false) . '</a></h4></div></div>';

    endwhile; else :

        get_template_part('template_parts/content','error');

    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    $return .= '</div></div>';
    
    return $return;
}
add_shortcode( 'get_latest_posts', 'get_latest_posts' );
```

Comment: I think `the_permalink()` and `the_title()` echo out their results though. ([They do](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_permalink/))

Comment: Good call! One min, let me fix that

Comment: Same for `the_post_thumbnail()`. Prefixing with `get_` should fix that

Comment: Oh WordPress ... the gift that keeps on giving

Comment: Thank you so much. I am still learning PHP and WordPress theming day by day (and don't understand the downvote for a question that is relevant for me) so I am glad for every piece of code that is helpful on my way! It works as it should now and I can continue!

Comment: PS: I just don't understand why sometimes you're getting the value with an additional get_ and sometimes you need to replace the_ . eg you're using get_permalink() instead of the_permalink(). But on the other hand get_the_post_thumbnail() instead of the_post_thumbnail(). I would have expected get_post_thumbnail() here. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: That's why I wanted to share the full code which @brombeer and I worked together on. I think it's important to keep learning and asking questions. I wouldn't worry about the negative votes on anything. I typically have 2-3 a day which I answer but someone doesn't like how I said something and downvotes me. I'm here to help and nitpicking on the way I said something isn't helpful.

Comment: Ahh ok, so this is because WordPress was made for those who aren't coders. I mean no disrespect there it's just the architecture displays things to make it easier to develop. They have getters now for uses like yours where it can't send to the screen right away. The best place to look is the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) as to what is available

Comment: sorry, I think I explained too badly what's confusing me. Sometimes you just replace the prefix "this_" with a "get_". So far so easy. But sometimes the "get_" is being added in front of the "this_" so that it becomes a "get_the_" ... I don't see a reason for this